# Stack 10 - UWP App for Windows 10 & Windows 10 Phone

Tags: app, windows, windows-uwp

**Update**

Stack 10 is now V 19.5.25 with new fluent design and few bug fixes. Screenshots will be updated shortly.

## About

Stack 10 is a UWP Stack Exchange client for Stack Exchange Network.

## Some of the features

- Browse/search for new questions
- Flag/Up vote/Down vote/Favorite
  others questions
- Edit your questions/answers from the app
- Flag/Up
  vote/Un Up vote others comments
- Edit/Delete your own comments
- Ask New questions/Add new Answers/Delete the same from the app
- Get Notifications on replies to your posts
- Open questions in New Windows (Desktop Only)
- Continue reading the same posts on multiple devices
- Save your frequently posted comments to reuse
- Cortana Integrated
  (Check About page)

## Screenshots ( More screenshots on the app store )

[image]
[image]

## Platform

Windows 10, Windows 10 Phone, Surface Hub

## Contact

If you have any request/concerns/Questions, please submit using the Feedback button on About Page.

You can also contact me at `avkapps@outlook.com`

[image: Get it from Microsoft]

Comment: What's the licence of it?