# Comments have incorrect `can_flag` values for at least 2 different API routes

Tags: bug, api-v2.2, comments

I am trying to see and show whether a comment on question/answer is flagged by the authenticated user.

1. But whenever I use [/questions/{ids}](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids), `can_flag` is `true` irregardless of whether the user (me) can actually flag the comment.
2. When I use [/comments/{ids}](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/comments-by-ids), I get the correct status.
3. *Editors note*: additional/updated/different info in the answer below, but this still looks like a set of bugs.

**Example:**

1. For [*The API Sandbox* question on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51812/the-api-sandbox):
2. In [this answer there (Id 54725)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51812/the-api-sandbox/54725#54725), **I flagged** the (now deleted) [comment with ID 764560](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51812/the-api-sandbox/54725#comment764560_54725) (Link now works only for SE devs and MetaSE moderators).
3. But the `/questions/{ids}` route shows `can_flag: true`, which is **incorrect**:

   [image: questions route shows incorrect can_flag]
4. However, using `/comments/{ids}` I get `can_flag: false`, which is **correct**:

   [image: comments route shows correct can_flag for flagged comment]
5. I also tried `/comments/{ids}` **for an unflagged comment** ([comment ID:396655](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51812/the-api-sandbox/54725#comment396655_54725)). It gives`can_flag: true`, which is **correct**:

   [image: comments route shows correct can_flag for unflagged comment]

Why is there an inconsistency? **This looks like a bug.**

---

Note: I did (re)check `/questions/{ids}` 30 minutes after flagging the comment.  So this does not seem to be a time-delay/caching issue.

Answer (score 1):

I can't replicate the bug as stated; **both `/questions/{ids}` and `/comments/{ids}` give the same results** which are:

1. `can_flag` is **false for my comments**.     ([Correct behavior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-and-flagging-work))
2. `can_flag` is true for comments posted by others.    (See next item)
3. `can_flag` is **true even for comments that I have an active flag on**.   ([**Wrong** behavior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281326/warn-me-for-trying-to-flag-comments-ive-already-flagged))

### Steps to replicate:

1. Go to [this API OAuth page](https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=1515&scope=read_inbox%20write_access%20private_info&redirect_uri=https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success) and authorize the application.
2. From the resulting value in your browser's address bar, copy out the `access_token` value.
   For example, if your browser is redirected to:

   ```
   https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success#access_token=OGuIJlBxxxMkj2Ola1jG1A))&expires=86400
   ```

   You want the `OGuIJlBxxxMkj2Ola1jG1A))`
3. Find a question with a comment you can **legitimately flag**; perhaps [the sandbox question on MetaSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox).
4. Add your own comment there.
5. Flag a single comment that legitimately deserves it (if any).
6. Visit this page in your browser (After updating the access_token):

   ```
   https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/3122/?access_token={INSERT VALUE FROM STEP 2 HERE}&site=meta&key=dp55hR5Wr9UhOJReA6F2gg((&filter=!pL7rWh2ni*lt.6(Pbf6bqCepl*I4sG)2VFlDiXzeex7895bjn0p3NcCGHCZb28uVIY
   ```

   It helps if you use Firefox or a browser/extension that formats the JSON for you.
7. Note that `can_flag` is false for your comment. (Correct)
8. In the JSON, find the comment you previously flagged (hopefully the comment and flag both still exist).  **Copy its ID.**
9. Visit this page in your browser (After updating the comment ID and the access_token):

   ```
   https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/comments/{INSERT VALUE FROM STEP 8 HERE}?access_token={INSERT VALUE FROM STEP 2 HERE}&site=meta&key=dp55hR5Wr9UhOJReA6F2gg((&filter=!1zSn*g7xPUqB4hiVTpmJB
   ```
10. Note that the comment's `can_flag` still shows as true -- **which is incorrect**.
11. Delete the comment you made in step 4, if appropriate.
12. Your `access_token` will expire in 24 hours.  Or you can deauthorize the app by following [these instructions](https://stackapps.com/a/7831/7653).

Comment: I forgot that i posted a question. the API Browser works fine. The issue is when i do a REST call, i need to include parameter `todate` and always post the current second like `Math.Floor(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds)` and it always brings the current status. This also happens with Questions api call. If you do not pass `todate`, you will keep receiving same questions over and over. Again this is only in REST Side. from API Browser it works fine.

Comment: @AVK, I don't see how that last comment is related to your bug report here at all.

Comment: IDK How SE is caching the calls but if i do not pass the parameter and if i make any number of subsequent calls, it always comes back as true. When i posted this question, i mentioned i tried after 30 mins. When i made the call after 30 mins, without the parameter, it comes back true. But if i pass the parameter `todate` with the value above, it comes back as `false`. You can see this in [Stack10](https://stackapps.com/q/7116).

Comment: @AVK, there is no mention of any date parameter in [your original bug report](https://stackapps.com/revisions/7144/1), nor the comment.  ... And it does not seem necessary to replicate this bug (as outlined in the answer, anyway).