# As a user, where in the web UI could I find all the tokens I have granted for Stack Apps?

Tags: support, oauth2

I want to manage or revoke access tokens I have granted to 3rd party Stack Apps, but I have a hard time to find them in the UI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Go to your profile: https://stackapps.com/users/current
2. Click the "Edit Profile & Settings" tab: https://stackapps.com/users/edit/current
3. Click "Applications" on the left sidebar (no handy universal link for this, but it'll take you to a URL like `https://stackapps.com/users/apps/53175` where 53175 is your user ID)

And there you'll have your list of authorized apps, with a little "remove" link next to each.